# How to draw blank map using Healpy

Tags: python, healpy

I am new in it, and cant fully understand the manual. I am running test code, but I want to make blank map, without this gradient colors. I think it's not hard for those who know. Help me please.[Here what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgG48.png)

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib as plt

NSIDE = 32
m = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
hp.mollview(m)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The numpy function `np.arange` gives out an array increasing from zero to 12288, which is why you have a gradient on your map.

You can replace that line of code to

```
m = np.zeros(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
```

if you want to treat blanks in your map as zeros, or to

```
m = np.full(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE), np.nan)
```

if you want to use `NaN` (not a number) value for the blank values on the map.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it returns green map. Solved it, by adding parameter to method hp.mollview(m, color = 'w')